# Delete vectors with at least two identical components

Tags: matrix, vector, algorithm

Given the matrix:

```
A := {{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, 
      {a, c, a}, {a, c, b}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, d}, {a, d, a}, {a, d, b}, {a, d, c}, {a, d, d}, 
      {b, a, a}, {b, a, b}, {b, a, c}, {b, a, d}, {b, b, a}, {b, b, b}, {b, b, c}, {b, b, d}, 
      {b, c, a}, {b, c, b}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, d}, {b, d, a}, {b, d, b}, {b, d, c}, {b, d, d}, 
      {c, a, a}, {c, a, b}, {c, a, c}, {c, a, d}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, b}, {c, b, c}, {c, b, d}, 
      {c, c, a}, {c, c, b}, {c, c, c}, {c, c, d}, {c, d, a}, {c, d, b}, {c, d, c}, {c, d, d}, 
      {d, a, a}, {d, a, b}, {d, a, c}, {d, a, d}, {d, b, a}, {d, b, b}, {d, b, c}, {d, b, d}, 
      {d, c, a}, {d, c, b}, {d, c, c}, {d, c, d}, {d, d, a}, {d, d, b}, {d, d, c}, {d, d, d}}
```

writing:

```
DeleteDuplicates[A, Total[#1] == Total[#2] &]
```

I get:

```
{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, d}, {a, d, d}, 
 {b, b, b}, {b, b, c}, {b, b, d}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, d}, {b, d, d}, {c, c, c}, {c, c, d}, {c, d, d}, {d, d, d}}
```

Now, I would write:

```
DeleteDuplicates[A, "??" &]
```

and obtain:

```
{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, b}, {a, c, d}, {a, d, b}, {a, d, c}, {b, a, c}, {b, a, d},
 {b, c, a}, {b, c, d}, {b, d, a}, {b, d, c}, {c, a, b}, {c, a, d}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, d},
 {c, d, a}, {c, d, b}, {d, a, b}, {d, a, c}, {d, b, a}, {d, b, c}, {d, c, a}, {d, c, b}}
```

What should I write instead of "??"

Thank you.

Comment: `Select[A, Length[Union[#]] == 3 &]`?

Comment: I'm not sure `DeleteDuplicates` is actually what you want! (See my above comment). As an aside, if you desire to directly generate your results you can do `Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {3}]`

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/how-do-you-check-if-there-are-any-equal-argumentseven-sublist-in-a-list) [also related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/how-do-you-check-if-there-are-any-equal-argumentseven-sublist-in-a-list) [also related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63225/pattern-for-finding-matches-that-are-different/63234#63234)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) on the list of vectors. Then you can use [`DuplicateFreeQ`](http://%22http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html%22):

```
ClearAll[desired];
desired = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, b}, {a, c, d}, {a, d, b}, {a, d, c},
           {b, a, c}, {b, a, d}, {b, c, a}, {b, c, d}, {b, d, a}, {b, d, c},
           {c, a, b}, {c, a, d}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, d}, {c, d, a}, {c, d, b},
           {d, a, b}, {d, a, c}, {d, b, a}, {d, b, c}, {d, c, a}, {d, c, b}};
Select[A, DuplicateFreeQ] === desired
(* True *)
```

If you have a pre-10.0 version of Mathematica, `DuplicateFreeQ` is equivalent to

```
Pillsy`DuplicateFreeQ[list_] := list === DeleteDuplicates[list];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for alternative ways: `Alternatives` maybe your friend ;-)

First:

```
rule = Alternatives @@ (Permutations@{x_, y_, x_}) :> Nothing
```

then

```
A /. rule
```